# "Analyse" the Python language to dissect a Scons build script?

Tags: java, python, reflection, jython, scons

I'm thinking about trying to convert a Scons (Python) script to another build system but was wondering if there was a Python-analysis library available in order to 'interrogate' the Scons/Python script?

What I'm [possibly] after is something along the lines of Java's reflection mechanism, in fact, if this is possible via say Jython/Java, coding in Java, that would be best for me as a Java dev (I have no real background in Python).

What I need to be able to do is extract the variable assigment values etc. for certain named class types and methods within the script, so that I can transfer them to my new output format.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Rich

Comment: You question isn't clear- please expand on "extract the variable assigment values etc. for certain named class types and methods." What are you trying to do? Can you give an example (say, some sample code and the kind of output you would want?) And what build system are you moving it to?

Answer (score 0):

If your current scons files are very regular and consistent it may be easier to do something "dumb" with standard text-editing tools.  If you want to get smarter, you should notice that scons is itself a Python program, and it loads your build files which are also Python.  So you could make your own "special" version of scons which implements the functions your build scripts use (to add programs, libraries, whatever).  Then you could run your build scripts in your "fake" scons program and have your functions dump their arguments in a format suitable for your new build system.

In other words, don't think of the problem in terms of analyzing the Python grammar completely--realize that you can actually run your build scripts as Python code and hijack their behavior.

Easier said than done, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's the best tool for migrating scons, but python's `inspect` module offers some reflection facilities. For the rest, you can simply poke inside live classes and objects: Python has some data hiding but does not enforce access restrictions.